# What does builtin commands means in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I read a part of manual of bash. The item is "COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT". The part says,

> Builtin commands that are invoked as part of a pipeline are also executed  in  a subshell  environment.   Changes  made  to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell's execution environment.

I suppose it means value changed in pipeline is local because each command in pipeline runs in its own sub-shell. Like following,

```
value='1'
echo "Before pipe, ${value}"
value='2' | echo "${value}" | value='3' | echo "In another pipe, ${value}"
echo "After pipe, ${value}"

Before pipe, 1
In another pipe, 1
After pipe, 1
```

I read "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" in bash. But I could not find "=" as builtin command. What does "builtin commands" means here? And are there "non-builtin commands" which can affect the change globally even in pipe-line?

And if you don't mind please let me know when the new sub-shell runs except for:

1. `(...)`
2. pipeline `|`

Comment: It's not stated explicitly, but an assignment by itself is effectively a command  with exit status 0 (assuming no command substitutions or process substitutions are embedded in the values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the manual is basically saying that built-in commands, such as `echo`, `printf`, `read`, etc. don't get any special treatment and still run within their own sub-shell, even though in principal it would be possible for the shell to determine that all of the commands in the pipeline could be run natively in the same shell.

If you ask to pipe one command into another, then sub-shells are created, no matter what is on either side of the pipe.

For example:

```
echo string | read foo
```

uses the two built-ins, `echo` and `read` but the variable `$foo` ceases to exist after the pipeline finishes.

Comment: I guess it's more about `cd`, `shopt`, `set`, etc.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf fair point, although I'm struggling to think of an example that uses those commands. Come to think of it, I'm struggling to think of an example in general!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but `cd`, `shopt` and `set` are very useful in subshells! `( cd directory || exit 1; do_stuff_here ) # back to where I was before, without needing to cd back`, etc.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Sure, agreed. Perhaps we've both interpreted the question differently...

Comment: The key point is that the shell forks first, *then* looks at what command is to be run in the resulting subshell.